# Python 3 - convert string into a number

Tags: python, django, int, sum, decimal

I'm working with python and django, and i have this problem: I have different variables storing the price of a object, all of them in a format like `350.32`, `182.40`, etc...

My problem is that these numbers are strings, but in my function i have to sum them to reach a total, and python won't let me do it because it can't sum strings. I've tried `int()`, `float()`, `format()`, and `Decimal()`, but they give me always a value with only one decimal number or other incorrect values. I need 2 decimal numbers and I need the possibility to sum them all. How can i do it?

PS: sorry for any english mistakes, i'm italian.

Comment: If these variables are Django model fields, have you considered to make them [`DecimalField`s](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) instead of whatever field type they are now?

Comment: Problem solved, i used float(number) to be able to sum all the prices and it works fine, then for the 2 decimal places, in my html page i used {{ total_price|floatformat:2 }}.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decimal seems to work for me.

If these are prices, do not store them as floats ... [floats will not give you exact numbers for decimal amounts like prices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = Decimal('1.23')
>>> b = Decimal('4.56')
>>> c = a + b
>>> c
Decimal('5.79')
```

Comment: @Suppose `a='50.13342'`. Is it possible to round this? When I try `>>>from decimal import Decimal` `>>>round(Decimal('123.1231231', 2))` it returns `123.0` for some reason. I am using Python 3.4.0. Even if I try `>>>round(Decimal('123.1231231', 5))` it returns the same thing (`123.0`).

Comment: @user2719875 Try giving the 2 or 5 to `round` instead of to `Decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Python 3.4.0, and this works for me:

```
>>>a = '350.32'
>>>float(a)
350.32
```

To round it to 2 decimal places, do this:

```
>>>b = '53.4564564'
>>>round(float(b), 2)
53.46
```

Comment: OP said these are prices.  [Storing prices as floats is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Comment: @ppperry True. I actually posted this just to show that I am using Python 3.4.0 and the conversion did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

eggs = "12.4, 15.5, 77.2"

print(sum(map(float, re.split("\s*,\s*", eggs))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This give perfect decimal values to five decimal places

```
import random
from decimal import Decimal  

def myrandom():
    for i in range(10):
        Rand = Decimal(random.random()* (0.909 - 0.101) + 0.101)
        Rand = '{0:0.5f}'.format(Rand)
        print (Rand)

myrandom()
```